# Header row fixing in a Google Chart table is not working

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I found out that, in theory, Google Chart is supposed to automatically fix the header row of a table when you scroll it down:

> "The header row remains fixed as the user scrolls." (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table - Overview)

For some strange reason, my table is not fixing the header row. Here's the code. I basically copied the same example code from Google's page (the link above) and put some 40 extra rows to it. Am I missing something? I've already tried in both Firefox and Chrome, same thing, no fixing.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Column0');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Column1'); 
        data.addRows([
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1],
          ['a',1]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_test'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_test" style="width: 200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work for you when using the exact code from the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a "height" property to the table, it will keep the header row at the top as you scroll vertically down the page. Using your example, just add the following to your options.

Your code:

```
table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
```

Adjusted code:

```
table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, height: 200});
```

This is useful if you have a large quantity of data you want someone to scroll, but it isn't what you think it is. If you wanted to have the row header 'float' you'd have to use absolute positioning and some fancy CSS to handle how it works when you scroll the page (assuming the page scrolls). Much easier just to use the height as stated above.